# Пропорциональное изменение высоты блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как изменить высоту блока, пропорционально изменению ширины его родителя, без перезагрузки страницы?

Написал два способа (первый закомментировал). Высота блока изменяется в обоих случаях но только после перезагрузки страницы.
Мне нужно, чтобы изменение происходило динамически. Это будет полезно, когда захотят изменить ширину окна или из полного экрана перейдут в оконный режим. Не перезагружать же страницу каждый раз.

```js
//var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
var width = parseInt($('.region-slider').css('width')),
  h = width / 2.051835853131749;
//alert(h);

$(".views-field-nothing").css('height', h);
```

```css
.region-slider {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="region-slider">
  <div class="views-field-nothing">


  </div>
</div>
```

[Тут](https://jsfiddle.net/d9tg4eot/9/) можно наглядно проверить, что с изменением ширины окна ничего не меняется пока не обновим страницу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вы не отслеживаете событие изменения страницы, поэтому ваш код выполнятся только один раз. Как-то так:

```
function myfun() {
var width = parseInt($('.region-slider').css('width')),
      h = width / 2.051835853131749;
   $(".views-field-nothing").css('height', h);
};

$( window ).resize(myfun);
$( document ).ready(myfun);
```

Comment: работает только перед ней пришлось оставить свои вычисления, а то пока окно не начну двигать и блок не появится

Comment: вы можете первый раз это выполнить при загрузке страницы, например, выделив в отдельную функцию

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d9tg4eot/10/  вот так написал, или можно более универсально?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d9tg4eot/11/

Comment: внес код  в ответ